# reversing a list in OCaml using fold_left/right

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, higher-order-functions, fold

### UPDATE - Solution

Thanks to jacobm for his help, I came up with a solution.

```
// Folding Recursion
let reverse_list_3 theList = 
    List.fold_left (fun element recursive_call -> recursive_call::element) [] theList;;
```

---

I'm learning about the different ways of recursion in OCaml (for class) and for some exercise, I'm writing a function to reverse a list using different recursion styles.

```
// Forward Recursion
let rec reverse_list_forward theList =
    match theList with [] -> [] | (head::tail) -> (reverse_list_1 tail) @ [head];;

// Tail Recursion
let rec reverse_list_tail theList result =
    match theList with [] -> result | (head::tail) -> reverse_list_2 tail (head::result);;
```

Now, I'm trying to write a reverse function using `List.fold_left` but I'm stuck and can't figure it out. How would I write this reverse function using folding?

Also, if anyone has good references on functional programming, the different types of recursion, higher-order-functions, etc..., links would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find it helpful to think of the fold operations as a generalization of what to do with a sequence of operations

```
a + b + c + d + e
```

`fold_right (+) 0` applies the `+` operation right-associatively, using `0` as a base case:

```
(a + (b + (c + (d + (e + 0)))))
```

`fold_left 0 (+)` applies it left-associatively:

```
(((((0 + a) + b) + c) + d) + e)
```

Now consider what happens if you replace `+` with `::` and `0` with `[]` in both right- and left-folds.

---

It may also be useful to think about the way `fold_left` and `fold_right` work as "replacing" the `::` and `[]` operators in a list. For instance, the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` is really just shorthand for `1::(2::(3::(4::(5::[]))))`. It may be useful to think of `fold_right op base` as letting you "replace" `::` with `op` and `[]` with `base`: for instance

```
fold_right (+) 0 1::(2::(3::(4::(5::[]))))
```

becomes

```
1 + (2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + 0))))
```

`::` became `+`, `[]` became `0`. From this perspective, it's easy to see that `fold_right (::) []` just gives you back your original list. `fold_left base op` does something a bit weirder: it rewrites all the parentheses around the list to go the other direction, moves `[]` from the back of the list to the front, and *then* replaces `::` with `op` and `[]` with `base`. So for instance:

```
fold_left 0 (+) 1::(2::(3::(4::(5::[]))))
```

becomes

```
(((((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5)
```

With `+` and `0`, `fold_left` and `fold_right` produce the same result. But in other cases, that's not so: for instance if instead of `+` you used `-` the results would be different: 1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - (5 - 0)))) = 3, but (((((0 - 1) - 2) - 3) - 4) - 5) = -15.

Comment: is the most nested `()` evaluated first?

Comment: In OCaml yes it is, though strictly speaking it doesn't matter when it's evaluated. The way the operations are grouped is all you need to think about.

Comment: What I meant was which addition was the deepest level of recursion, i.e., when I reach the base case?

Comment: Yes that's right. I also just edited my response to give another perspective that might help as well.

Comment: take a look at my solution... let me know if you have comments! thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, you got it. Notice that all your function is doing is reversing the order of arguments to `(::)`; in other words, `fold_left` is almost just a generalization of the reverse function already! One of the neat mind-expanding connections that makes functional programming fun to do.

Comment: :) thank you! If I could upvote more, I would. Last question, this problem can't be done using `fold_right`, right?

Comment: It can, but not efficiently. At every step of the fold you'd need to take the first element in the list and put it at the _end_ of the accumulated list. This requires traversing the entire list-so-far at each step (to put the new element at the end), which leads to an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
let rev =
  List.fold_left ( fun lrev b ->
    b::lrev
  ) [];;
```

test:

```
# rev [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [4; 3; 2; 1]
```