# I'm in trouble with writing reversing list function in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml, reverse

```
let rec reverse l =
  let s = ref [] in
    match l with
    | [] -> !s
    | hd::tl -> s := hd :: !s
                reverse tl
```

Maybe I'm in trouble with the last `s := hd :: !s` part.

How can I fix this??

Comment: This is either a duplicate of or highly resembles [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286668/list-reversing-in-ocaml), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221053/ocaml-reverse-a-list) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382140/reversing-a-list-in-ocaml-using-fold-left-right) StackOverflow question. Also, this problem has been answered in countless other resources you'd reach if you googled "reversing a list in ocaml". It seems that what you need is basic programming help with OCaml and that this question holds very little value to future problem solvers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you have two expressions:

```
s := hd :: !s
reverse tl
```

You need to join these expressions into a larger expression that evaluates them in order. The way to do this is with the `;` (semicolon) operator:

```
s := hd :: !s ;
reverse tl
```

Your other problem is that you have a different `s` in each recursive call. You need to use the same `s` for all the calls.

The basic layout for doing this is to have an outer function that defines `s` and an inner recursive function that does the work using this one `s`:

```
let outer_fun l =
    let s = ref [] in
    let rec inner_fun = ... in
    inner_fun l
```

(As a side comment, it might be worth figuring out a way to do this without using a reference. Learning to write pure functions is one of the biggest benefits of learning OCaml, even if you don't go on to be a functional programmer.)